# Differences between "import module" and "from . import module" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Recently I found there are weird errors when using "import M" and "from . import M". I am using python3.6.
For example, the Doucment tree are as belows.

```
test/
├── pacA
│   ├── a1.py
│   ├── a2.py
│   └── utils.py
├── test_a1.py
└── test_a2.py
```

In utils.py is func printer:

```py
def printer(info):
    print(info)
```

In a1.py is:

```py
from .utils import printer

def pa():
    printer('printer called in a1.pa()\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printer('pinter called in a1.__main__\n')
```

In a2.py is:

```py
from utils import printer

def pa():
    printer('printer called in a2.pa()\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printer('pinter called in a2.__main__\n')
```

We can see that both a1.py and a2.py want to import printer in utils.py. And they are using different import methods. This is the only difference.
When I running a1.py no matter from directory pacA/ or not, I get error below:

```
from .utils import printer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.utils'; '__main__' is not a package
```

But running a2.py will get the correct answer.

However, if I use another .py to import a1 and a2, things turn around. In test_a1.py, code is like:

```py
from pacA import a1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1.pa()
```

In test_a2.py, code is like:

```py
from pacA import a2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a2.pa()
```

When I run test_a1.py no matter from test/ or not, I get the correct answer. However, when I run test_a2.py, I get error like:

```
from pacA import a2
  File "/home/gph/Desktop/test/pacA/a2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import printer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

How shold I import utils.py in a1 to make both situation right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
pip install utils
```

python wants you to install utils package externally

Hope this helps

Comment: It is just an example, I do not want to install that package. I just get puzzled by the import method. And want to know what is truly happenning.

Comment: ok listen, so i think this is what happening here?

in a1.py you are importing th utils package using .utils that's correct because utilts is located in the root directory

Comment: But that's not the case in a2.py as you are trying to directly importing utils package .
To do that the utils package must be located in the test directory outside pacA directory

Answer (score 0):

I think I have find the reason behind this.

For the first error, I shold not run a1.py directly.
When you use relative import `from .utils import printer` in a1.py, then you should not run a1.py directly. If so, you will get error `'__main__' is not a package"`. To understand this, you need to know how `if __name__==__main__` works.

When using `from utils import printer` in a2.py, python will search the classical paths, including in the sys.path. But if you run test_a2.py, pacA is not included, so we can not find it.If you want to run test.a2.py, then you should include this `sys.path.append('path to pacA')` before importing utils.